# Firebase function to get ranking

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am new to firebase and would like to implement the ranking for the players stored in the rank table from firebase real-time db, see screenshot below:
[image: my firebase db ranking table]

I have also setup the rules for the index:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null",
      "TH": {
        "rank": {
        ".indexOn" : ["balance", "w_rate","match"]  
        }
      }
  }
}
```

in my firebase function, I have a function as a post request to get the rank:

```
exports.getRank = functions.https.onRequest(async (req,res) => {

    const user_id = req.query.id;
    console.log(`user_id ${user_id} `);
    const query = database().ref('TH/rank')
                    .orderByChild('balance')
                    .limitToLast(30)

    query.once('value',function(snapshot) {

        console.log('in side the usersRef');
        console.log(`snapshot:${JSON.stringify(snapshot.val())}`);

        let current_user_rank = 0;

        if (user_id !== null) {

            console.log(`user id ${user_id} isn't null`);

            database().ref('TH/rank/').orderByChild('balance').once('value',function(all_snapshot){
                let index = 0;
                console.log(`user id ${user_id} all snapshot.`);

                if (all_snapshot.child(`${user_id}`).exists()) {
                    console.log(`user id ${user_id} exists`);
                    const current_user_data = all_snapshot.child(`${user_id}`).val();
                    all_snapshot.forEach( child => {
                        index += 1;
                        console.log(child.key, child.val());
                        if(child.key === user_id) {
                            current_user_rank = all_snapshot.numChildren() - index;
                        }
                    });
                    res.json({
                        user: { id: user_id,
                                rank: current_user_rank,
                                data: current_user_data
                        },
                        rank: snapshot.val()
                    });

                } else {
                    res.json({
                        user: { id: user_id,
                                rank: current_user_rank,
                                data: null
                        },
                        rank: snapshot.val()
                    });
                }
            }).catch();

        } else {
            
            res.json({
                user: { id: user_id,
                        rank: current_user_rank,
                        data: null
                },
                rank: snapshot.val()
            });
            
        }
    }).catch();
});
```

However, the result isn't correct, it seems the **orderByChild** doesn't work at all.  Can someone help on this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several problems with your Cloud Function:

1. You use `async` when declaring the callback but you never use `await` in the Cloud Function, in order to get the result of the asynchronous [`once()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database.Reference#once) method.
2. Instead of using the callback "flavor" of the `once()` method (i.e. `ref.once('value',function(snapshot) {..}`), use the promise "flavor" (i.e., with await: `await ref.once('value');`).
3. The result is that you don't correctly manage the Cloud Function life cycle. For more details on how to do that correctly, I would suggest you watch the 3 videos about "JavaScript Promises" from the [Firebase video series](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/video-series/)  as well as read the following [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions).

So the following should do the trick. (Note that I've just adapted it to correctly manage the life cycle, I've not tested the business logic).

```
exports.getRank = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {

    try {

        const user_id = req.query.id;
        console.log(`user_id ${user_id} `);

        let current_user_rank = 0;

        if (user_id !== null) {

            console.log(`user id ${user_id} isn't null`);

            const baseQuery = database().ref('TH/rank/').orderByChild('balance');

            const query = baseQuery.limitToLast(30);

            const snapshot = await query.once('value');

            console.log(`snapshot:${JSON.stringify(snapshot.val())}`);

            const all_snapshot = await baseQuery.once('value');

            let index = 0;
            console.log(`user id ${user_id} all snapshot.`);

            if (all_snapshot.child(`${user_id}`).exists()) {
                console.log(`user id ${user_id} exists`);
                const current_user_data = all_snapshot.child(`${user_id}`).val();
                all_snapshot.forEach(child => {
                    index += 1;
                    console.log(child.key, child.val());
                    if (child.key === user_id) {
                        current_user_rank = all_snapshot.numChildren() - index;
                    }
                });
                res.json({
                    user: {
                        id: user_id,
                        rank: current_user_rank,
                        data: current_user_data
                    },
                    rank: snapshot.val()
                });

            } else {
                res.json({
                    user: {
                        id: user_id,
                        rank: current_user_rank,
                        data: null
                    },
                    rank: snapshot.val()
                });
            }

        } else {

            res.json({
                user: {
                    id: user_id,
                    rank: current_user_rank,
                    data: null
                },
                rank: snapshot.val()
            });
        }

    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        res.status(500).send(error);
    }

});
```

---

#### Update following your comment:

You need to use `forEach()` in order to get the children correctly ordered, and not `snapshot.val()`. `snapshot.val()` displays the children according to their key, exactly like they are ordered in the DB. The following adaptation of the code in your comment works correctly:

```
exports.getSortedRank = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {

    try {
        const obj = {};
        const baseQuery = admin.database().ref('TH/rank/').orderByChild('balance');
        const query = baseQuery.limitToLast(10);
        const snapshot = await query.once('value');
        snapshot.forEach(childSnapshot => {
            console.log(childSnapshot.val());
            obj[childSnapshot.key] = childSnapshot.val()
        });
        res.json({ rank: obj });
    } catch (error) { console.log(error); res.status(500).send(error); }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However, it won't work. I have tested a simpler version, attached below: exports.getSortedRank = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {try { const baseQuery = database().ref('TH/rank/').orderByChild('balance');
const query = baseQuery.limitToLast(10);
const snapshot = await query.once('value');
            res.json({
                rank: snapshot.val()
            });
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
            res.status(500).send(error);
        }
    
    }); but still returned as the original order

Comment: BTW, how do you define `database()`? Can you share the entire `index.js` file please? Also, when you say "it seems the orderByChild doesn't work at all", what do you mean? Do you get a result but not ordered OR no result at all?

Comment: In addition, note that with the code in your comment, by doing `res.json({ rank: snapshot.val() })` you indeed get the children ordered **by key**. You need to use **forEach** in order to get the result ordered by `balance` value, see the update.

Comment: Hi matee, did you have time to look at the proposed solution?

Comment: Hi Renaud, thx for the solution. As you said the ordered result needs to use forEach in order to get the result rather than snapshot.val(). thanks a lot.